# Appending an image to a link based on its content

Tags: css, image

I have a system that generated links to different parts of the application. I need to append an image next to the link based on its context. In CSS I would do it like this:

```
a {    
 color:#FF6600;
 padding-right:50px;
 background-image: url('images/system.png');
 background-position: right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

The problem with the above CSS rule is that all links get the same image.If a link has class="system" then system.png must be appended and if its got class="actions" action.png must be appended. I am guessing I could use jQuery to do this, any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a {
    color: #f60;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a.system {
    background-image: url("images/system.png");
}

a.actions {
    background-image: url("images/actions.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
a.system{
background-image: url('images/system.png');
.....
}
a.actions{
background-image: url('images/action.png');
....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add IDs to the link. Use jQuery to select each ID, and change its `background-image` attribute to match what you need.

example:

for `<a id="house" src="house.html">my house</a>`

execute:

`$("#house").attr("background-image", "house.png");`.

Of course you can iterate over all links programatically, as long as their ID hints at the image you need to set.

Comment: using jQuery for this simple thing is an overkill

Comment: Depending on how many such links he has. For 2-3, I totally agree. For a whole list, a manual approach is not recommended, or maintainable.

Comment: How would `$("#house").attr("background-image", "house.png");` be more practical on the large scale? You would need to do it for each link if you're going off the `ID` where as setting a specific image with css `a.system { }` will work on say 100 links under the class name `system`